# Cost of clustering index vs non-clustering

Tags: sql, indexing

I came across an exercise from an SQL and databases book I am reading and I am confused on how can I calculate the costs of clustering index vs non-clustering in I/O. For example:

R has a non-custering index on `R.a`:
 
20.000 rows
1000 pages (of memory) in size
`R.a` has 20 unique values

S has a custering index on `S.c`:
40.000 rows
400 pages (of memory) in size
`S.c` has 200 unique values

If I selected * from R where `R.a = 100` what would the cost in I/O be ?

If I selected * from S where `S.c = 50` what would the cost in I/O be ?

How is it possible to calculate that cost ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make some assumptions and guesstimate.  For this query:

```
select r.* from R where R.a = 100
```

First you want to figure out how many records and then how many pages.  Given that there are 20 values *and then* assuming that the distribution of values is uniform, then about 1/20 records will match.  Each page contains about 20 records (20,000 rows / 1,000 pages).  So, without getting into complicated statistics, there is about one matching record on each page.

So, the I/O overhead is about 1,000 pages plus whatever is needed for the index.

The second query needs to read about 1/200 records, or about 200 records.  A page contains 100 records.  However, the index is clustered so the 200 records are not distributed randomly; they are all on the adjacent pages.  It is doubtful that a page starts exactly on a given value, so let's call this 3 pages of data plus the index overhead.